# Недействительный IP адрес

Tags: c++, python, c, сокет, сеть

Какой IP адрес будет 100% недействителен. То есть какое 32 битное поле можно использовать, как значение того, что IP не задан коректно. Храниться будет в struct sockaddr. По возможности хочется избежать проверки .sa_family, те будет неприемлимо ни для IPv4 ни для IPv6, в случае приведения к нему. Неприемлимо означает - то, что вероятность такого адреса крайне мала или отсутствует. Это будет использоваться только для x64.

Comment: Чем не устраивает 127.0.0.1?

Comment: 255.255.255.255 broadcast. его никогда нельзя использовать

Comment: Эта штука применяется в proxy, который запущен на машине на которой есть web-сервер который нужен для конфигурации этого proxy Соответственно если по какой-то причине для бэк-енд сервера будет задан неправильный ip (который как вы предлагаете может быть 127.0.0.1) то вместо бэк-энд сервера будет отвечать сервер отвечающий за конфигурацию собственно прокси, что безусловно неприемлимо.

Comment: А куда денутся пакеты если их послать по адресу 255.255.255.255 ?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - 127.255.255.255 это loopback. IP валидный и используется для локальной проверки порта. Все пакеты возврашаются обратно. На другой порт не уходит.

Answer (score 4):

Не совсем понятно, как это будет использоваться, но в качестве наиболее очевидного выбора я бы рекомендовал **`0.0.0.0`**.
Достоинства: пакетов с таким исходящим адресом не бывает (т. е. в этом узком смысле адрес не может быть назначен).
Недостаток: при попытке соединить (connect) сокет с этим IP, через BSD sockets, мы попадаем на произвольный локальный интерфейс машины. Нет-нет, не рассказывайте мне про `127.0.0.1` — адрес на интерфейсе loopback. При открытии `127.0.0.1` мы тоже попадаем на свою машину, но сокет сядет *конкретно на интерфейс loopback,* а вот куда он сядет при открытии `0.0.0.0`, зависит от реализации.

Если хочется безопасности в том смысле, чтобы (даже в случае отсутствия проверок на равенство IP специальному значению) соединение сокета с IP специального назначения не приводило ни к чему, то возьмите **`127.255.255.255`** — connect на предложенный IP отказывает в Linux даже с root-привилегиями.***** К тому же, он принадлежит 127.0.0.0/8 и, следовательно, ни при каких условиях не уйдёт дальше первого исправного маршрутизатора. И он является широковещательным адресом в указанной сети, т. е. пакет с таким исходящим IP опять-таки появиться не должен (для сравнения, исходящий `255.255.255.255` бывает в пакетах протокола DHCP).

Что будет происходить при приведении данных адресов к IPv6?
Уточните, приведение каким образом имеется в виду, и я дополню ответ.

---

***** Если не делать setsockopt(*sock*, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, … ). Если делать (как в приложениях ping и netcat с ключом `-b`) — поведение API для `127.255.255.255` не отличается от `255.255.255.255`: connect проходит. Только в случае `255.255.255.255` пакеты в самом деле уходят в сеть, а в случае `127.255.255.255` — никуда физически не идут (при исправной настройке loopback).

Comment: Да, 127.255.255.255 это интересное предложение. А connect на INADDR_NONE == 255.255.255.255 разве проходит?

Comment: @avp: По ICMP и с SO_BROADCAST — представьте себе. Попробуйте под Линуксом # `strace ping -bc 1 255.255.255.255`

Comment: А connect--то (это же tcp/sctp) тут причем? ICMP это по сути такой же датаграммный протокол, как и UDP (по которому работает упоминаемый Вами DHCP).

Comment: @avp: Ну раз провели сравнение с UDP, встречный вопрос: доводилось что-то отправлять по UDP через BSD sockets? Сколько способов отправлять UDP-пакеты знаете?

Comment: Один -- системный вызов write в разных ипостасях.

Comment: @avp: Путём write можно отправить UDP-пакет. Некоторые приложения так и поступают, к примеру netcat(1). Но, чтобы система знала IP/port назначения, с сокетом надо сделать что?

Comment: А, вот какой connect Вы имели ввиду. И что, с ним 127.255.255.255 не пройдет, EAFNOSUPPORT в errno вернется?

Comment: Сравнение 127.255.255.255 и 255.255.255.255 добавлено в ответ.

@avp: Как не странно, у меня (без `-b`) возвращается EACCES. Но запустите сами под strace(1), и увидите.

Comment: EACCES тоже возможно -- `The user tried to connect to a broadcast address without  having
              the  socket  broadcast  flag  enabled  or the connection request
              failed because of a local firewall rule.` Тем более Вы похоже играетесь с ping (а там raw сокет и на самом деле не UDP).

Comment: @avp: Я проверял и ping и nc, как можно заметить,  п р о ч т я   о б н о в л е н и е   о т в е т а . Кто утверждал, что в ping UDP? Там сокеты других протоколов (IPPROTO_ICMP и IPPROTO_IP), причём на втором из них в самом деле совершается connect. Я правда не могу понять, зачем, а в исходники сейчас не полезу.

IPPROTO_IP (как у ping) или IPPROTO_UDP (как у nc) — поведение connect одно.

Comment: Что-то я Вас теперь не совсем понимаю (раньше думал, что понимал, что мы просто трепемся "на заданную тему" слегка подкалывая друг друга (особенно после `Сколько способов отправлять UDP-пакеты знаете?`), но в принципе оба понимаем, о чем речь). А Вы похоже серьезно? / На самом деле я подозревал, что говоря о прокси ТС имеет в виду tcp connect (отсюда и все мои подколки про broadcast адреса). / А connect (да, его можно делать и для datagram socket) в ping делается для того, чтобы сразу присвоить сокету постоянный destination addr (а не каждый раз в sendto(), как обычно делают в учебниках).

Comment: Разумеется, мне известно, что TCP не может работать с широковещательным назначением. Но просили привести недействительный IP — я привёл таковой безотносительно к протоколу, с перестраховкой, чтоб уж никак.

Answer (score 0):

`255.255.255.255` broadcast - его никогда нельзя использовать

P.S. Если это правильный ответ, пусть поможет и другим...

UPDATE

от **`Gurman`** *Спасибо SD я так и поступлю. **254.255.255.255 + iptables***

Comment: А куда денутся пакеты если их послать по адресу 255.255.255.255 ?

Comment: и еще я думаю что 255.255.255.255 "в конце" IPv6 вполне валидно. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: 255.255.255.255 это IP адрес рассылки. Пикеты не куда не пойдут. Роутер остановить такие пакеты.

Comment: @Gurman вы правы, для IPv6 это валидный IP но задаче сказано что нужно 32 битное значение. Если у них IPv6 то нужно просто заполнить все поля единицами

Comment: Это не у них а у меня)) Роутер далеко. Куда они пойдут внутри моего линуксового сетевого стека? не начнет ли на них какой-нить сервер отвечать. По аналогии с адресами 127.0.0.1 и 0.0.0.0

Comment: '    bool update_in_sockaddr(struct sockaddr& rsa) const {
        if (isIPv4()) {
            if (rsa.sa_family == AF_INET6) {
                LOG( LOG_INFO, "IPv6 ch-d to IPv4");
            }
            rsa.sa_family = AF_INET;
            memcpy(&((sockaddr_in *)&rsa)->sin_addr, &(uip.w32[3]), sizeof(in_addr));
            return true;
        }

        if (rsa.sa_family == AF_INET) {
            LOG( LOG_INFO, "IPv4 ch-d to IPv6");
        }
        rsa.sa_family = AF_INET6;
        memcpy(&(((struct sockaddr_in6*)&rsa)->sin6_addr), &uip, sizeof(in6_addr));
        return true;
    }'

Comment: Как тут код вставить?

Comment: 255.255.255.255/32 Ограниченный широковещательный адрес. Чаще всего используется как адрес назначения при поиске DHCP серверов. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4

Comment: Там я попатался вставить функцию которая не сильно задумываясь апдатит struct sockaddr Хочется чтобы без излишнего овехеда она возвращала невалидный адрес. Вопрос 1 какой? Вопрос 2 Можно даже ей послать что-то в struct sockaddr& rsa невалидное чтоб она не задумывалась ЧТО?

Comment: SD я знаю про широковещание Я не знаю что с широковещанием происходит внутри линкс нэт стека

Comment: Если вы используете функция http://www.alhem.net/Sockets/html/classUtility.html#d0975ab4aae111318f2bc567966d4514 тогда она дасть вам всегда true. Дайте библиотеку что вы используете, может найдем исходник и можно будет проверить

Comment: Библиотека здесь не при чем это обынчные socket (просто лень сейчас смотреть какие именно). Меня вполне устроит если ответ библиотечной фенкции будет  true, но  в реале никто на не ответит на запрос на установку tcp соединения, посланный по этому адресу. Cкорее всего это будет именно просто попытка установить tcp соединение под http запросом. То есть HTTP поверх tcp Конечно стоит еще проверить, что будет если на вход нашему прокси прийдет что-то отличное от HTTP но на 80 порт Но здесь вы уже врядли поможете.

Comment: Вам проверить это трудно, у вас на машине не крутиться столько серверов/сервисов и таких как у меня.)) Но поугадывать и предположить Вы можете. Они ведь все написаны через как их называют берклей-сокеты Если я не ошибаюсь И ранятся на обычном линкс-стеке Ничего самописного на низком уровне вроде как нет))

Comment: Наверно нужно забубенить, что-нибудь типа 254.255.255.255 и все будет работать))

Comment: Если это не проверка функции а соединение socket`a тогда вы спокойно можете использовать зарезервированные IP адреса.  1) Если у вас нет сервиса на 80 порту тогда используйте адреса 127.0.0.1-127.255.255.255  2) если они у вас есть используйте адреса 254.0.0.0-255.255.255.255 так как эти все адреса считаются служебными и никакой сервер вам соединение tcp на эти адреса не дать  3) в linux создайте правило для iptables что бы он блокировал тот адрес который вы хотите использовать. И ВСЕ

Comment: Спасибо SD я так и поступлю. 254.255.255.255 + iptables